# Позиционирование модального окна по вертикали

Tags: javascript, html, css, выравнивание, margin

Есть модальное окно

```js
let modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
let modalcontent = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-content')[0];
let loginlink = document.getElementById('loginlink');

let elemclose = document.getElementsByClassName("closeregwindow")[0];

loginlink.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}


elemclose.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  display: none;
}

.modal-content {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  position: relative;
}

.closeregwindow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.b-footer__container {
  background-color: #000;
}

.loginsignuptext {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="closeregwindow">&times;</span>
      <h2>Шапка модального окна</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Какой-то текст в теле модального окна</p>
      <p>Ещё другой текст...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Футер модального окна</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<footer id="pageFooter">
  <div class="b-footer__container">
    <div class="b-footer-menu">
      <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
        <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="0">
            <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/about-us">
              Интернет-магазин
            </a>
            <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="0" style="display: none;">
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/about-us" class="b-footer-menu__link">О нас</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/delivery" class="b-footer-menu__link">Доставка</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/pay" class="b-footer-menu__link">Оплата</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/kredit" class="b-footer-menu__link">Покупка в кредит</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/e-catalog" class="b-footer-menu__link">Электронный каталог</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/special-offers" class="b-footer-menu__link">Акции</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/news" class="b-footer-menu__link">Новости</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/reviews" class="b-footer-menu__link">Обзоры</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/personal" class="b-footer-menu__link">Условия продажи<br> и политика обработки<br> персональных данных</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/services/card2card" class="b-footer-menu__link">Денежные переводы<br> с карты на карту</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/services/creditpayment" class="b-footer-menu__link">Оплата кредита онлайн</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/services/moneytransfer" class="b-footer-menu__link">Денежные переводы онлайн</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
        <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="1">
            <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/company">
              Компания
            </a>
            <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="1" style="display: none;">
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/history" class="b-footer-menu__link">Кто мы</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/catalog/elektronika-optom" class="b-footer-menu__link">Корпоративным клиентам</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/owner_of_real" class="b-footer-menu__link">Арендодателям</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/charity" class="b-footer-menu__link">Благотворительность</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://job.svyaznoy.ru/" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Работа в «Связном»</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/contacts" class="b-footer-menu__link">Контакты</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/anticorruption" class="b-footer-menu__link">Политика по&nbsp;противодействию<br>коррупции</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
        <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="2">
            <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/help">
              Помощь покупателю
            </a>
            <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="2" style="display: none;">
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/support/feedback/add-review" class="b-footer-menu__link">Обратная связь</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/shops" class="b-footer-menu__link">Адреса магазинов</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/obmen_vozvrat_remont" class="b-footer-menu__link">Обмен, возврат и ремонт</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/guarantee" class="b-footer-menu__link">Гарантия</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/support/repair-status" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Статус ремонта</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/support/contacts/addresses" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Адреса сервисных центров</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/service" class="b-footer-menu__link">Дополнительные услуги и сервис</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="3">
            <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/press_center">
              Пресс-центр
            </a>
            <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
          </div>
          <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="3" style="display: none;">
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/history" class="b-footer-menu__link">История</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/mission" class="b-footer-menu__link">Миссия и ценности</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/news/press" class="b-footer-menu__link">Пресс-релизы</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/media_about_us" class="b-footer-menu__link">СМИ о нас</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UhyjwJ6wZbUX-UxlFVTELnYi8bnxuhmg" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Фотографии</a></li>
            <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/contacts_for_media" class="b-footer-menu__link">Контакты для прессы</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
        <div class="b-footer-menu__col is-mobile-not">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__contacts">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__header _xl">
              <a href="tel:84952870000">8 (495) 287-00-00</a>
            </div>
            Интернет-магазин
            <div class="b-footer-menu__header _xl">
              <a href="tel:88007005000">8 (800) 700-50-00</a>
            </div>
            Связной Поддержка
            <div class="b-footer-menu__header _xl">
              <a href="tel:88007009922">8 (800) 700-99-22</a>
            </div>
            Корпоративным клиентам
          </div>
          <div class="b-footer-menu__socials">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/svyaznoy.ru" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon-fb"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://vk.com/svyaznoy" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon-vk"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/svyaznoy_ru" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/svyaznoy_russia/?hl=ru" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="b-footer-menu__ga">
            <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop" target="_blank" class="_gp" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a><br>
            <a href="https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki/id1062774471" target="_blank" class="_as" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/apps.apple.com\/ru\/app\/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki\/id1062774471&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
            <br>
            <a href="https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/marketshare/app/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139" target="_blank" class="_ag" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/appgallery.cloud.huawei.com\/marketshare\/app\/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="b-footer-border">
      <div class="b-footer-border__inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="b-footer-rel" data-footer-col="">
      <div class="b-footer-menu__header is-mobile-only" data-accordion-btn="4">
        Другие проекты
        <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="b-footer-rel__list" data-accordion-target="4" style="display: none;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="b-footer-bottom">
      <div class="b-footer-copy-wrapper">
        <div class="b-footer-copy">© ООО «Сеть Связной» 2002—2021. Все права защищены. Указанная в интернет-магазине цена товаров и условия их приобретения действительны на текущую дату.</div>
      </div>
      <a class="b-footer-stop-covid _big lazy lazy-loaded" href="https://ecomvscovid.ru/" target="_blank" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.svyaznoy.ru/upload/web/svyaznoy/img/footer/covidlogo.svg&quot;);">
        Зона безопасного сервиса. Стоп COVID.
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile">
      <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__row">
        <div class="b-footer-menu__socials">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/svyaznoy.ru" target="_blank">
            <i class="icon-fb"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="https://vk.com/svyaznoy" target="_blank">
            <i class="icon-vk"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/svyaznoy_ru" target="_blank">
            <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/svyaznoy_russia/?hl=ru" target="_blank">
            <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__right-col">
          <a class="b-footer-stop-covid _small lazy" data-original="https://cdn.svyaznoy.ru/upload/web/svyaznoy/img/footer/covidlogo.svg" href="https://ecomvscovid.ru/" target="_blank">
            Зона безопасного сервиса. Стоп COVID.
          </a>
          <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__tel">
            <a class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__tel-link" href="tel:8 (495) 287-00-00">8 (495) 287-00-00</a>
            <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__tel-descr">Интернет магазин</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="b-footer-menu__ga _mobile">
        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop" target="_blank" class="_gp" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
        <a href="https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki/id1062774471" target="_blank" class="_as" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/apps.apple.com\/ru\/app\/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki\/id1062774471&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
        <a href="https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/marketshare/app/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139" target="_blank" class="_ag" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/appgallery.cloud.huawei.com\/marketshare\/app\/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</footer>
```

В результате на экран выводится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

несмотря на

```
.modal-content {
z-index: 20;
border: 2px solid red;
padding: 15px;
width: 50%;
height: 70%;
margin: auto;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Как добиться полного выравнивания модального окна по центру (включая по вертикали)?

Comment: Всего 4 показа - ужас.

Comment: Если б ваш код запускался, а вы воспользовались [поиском](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-align-modal-content-box-to-center-of-any-screen/) то показов могло быть и больше.

Comment: используйте flex для центрирования у .modal